# How can I find all of the indices of a string in a different string?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, indexof, indices

My question is pretty straight forward, how can I find all the indices of a string inside of another string? This is the code I wrote but the problem is that all it does is return the exact same index multiple times. Here it is:

```
    public static int[] IndicesOf(this string s, string Search, int StartIndex)
    {
        List<int> indices = new List<int>();
        int lastIndex = 0;
        lastIndex = s.IndexOf(Search);
        while (lastIndex != -1)
        {
            indices.Add(lastIndex);
            lastIndex = s.IndexOf(Search, lastIndex);
        }
        return indices.ToArray();
    }
```

I don't know what is wrong with this code. I think I may need to advance the index before the next search.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that you should add 1 to your second `s.IndexOf` call.

That is:

```
lastIndex = s.IndexOf(Search, lastIndex + 1);
```

Comment: All I had done was not noticed I had to advance the index, thanks for the help, this can be closed now.